# Positioning UIButtons at top of Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

What I want is to have 5 buttons equally spaced out at the top of the screen. I tried using constraints but the buttons would get squished.

I have this code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //I know this is only two buttons
    NSUInteger space =  (_backround.frame.size.width - _squareOne.frame.size.width  * 5) / 6;
    CGRect newFrameOne;
    newFrameOne = CGRectMake(space, 50, 55, 55);
    CGRect newFrameTwo;
    newFrameTwo = CGRectMake(space * 2 + _squareOne.frame.size.width, 50, 55, 55);
    _squareOne.frame = newFrameOne;
    _squareTwo.frame = newFrameTwo;
}
```

The buttons never show up... and I don't know any other ways to do this...

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this below?

Update: I've written the code properly using Xcode this time (previously I typed it from memory).

See below screenshot for the final result.

### View Controller Header File

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn4;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn5;


@end
```

### View Controller Implementation File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
}


-(void)initViews
{
    self.btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.btn2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.btn2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.btn3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.btn3.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.btn4 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.btn4.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.btn5 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.btn5.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];



    [self.view addSubview:self.btn1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btn2];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btn3];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btn4];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btn5];
}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    self.btn1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btn2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btn3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btn4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btn5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"btn1": self.btn1,
                 @"btn2": self.btn2,
                 @"btn3": self.btn3,
                 @"btn4": self.btn4,
                 @"btn5": self.btn5
                 };

    // horizontal constraints

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[btn1]-5-[btn2(==btn1)]-5-[btn3(==btn1)]-5-[btn4(==btn1)]-5-[btn5(==btn1)]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // vertical constraints
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btn1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:5.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btn2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.btn1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btn3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.btn1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btn4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.btn1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btn5 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.btn1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

### Result

This is what I get.

[image: screenshot]

What long black strip are you referring to, the battery indicator?

Comment: It works, but there is a black long strip running down the right side of the button. Can you change your code to fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by black strip, see my above screenshot for what it should look like.

Comment: I use 55x55 uibuttons initialized in the h file. And they have a black strip running down the right side of the button as well as the bottom. The width is about 20 pixels.