# When animating UIButton can't be touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have looked at [UIButton can't be touched while animated with UIView animateWithDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/uibutton-cant-be-touched-while-animated-with-uiview-animatewithduration) and the answer doesn't help me.

```
for (UIButton *button in self.buttonsOutletCollection)
```

This part is the one that is confusing. My button isn't part of a IBOutletCollection so this doesn't work. I use this to move the button:

```
- (void) squareOneMover {
    CGRect oldFrame = _squareOne.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x , oldFrame.origin.y + 500, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
                         _squareOne.frame = newFrame;
                     }
                     completion:nil
    ];
}
```

I don't want to have to move the Button in small amounts because I need five buttons and it would be inefficient.

Can someone provide me with an answer similar to the question above that is for `UIButtons` not include in any array?

Edit:
The `UIButton` is defined in the interface file and connected to Interface Builder, and is `strong` and `nonamatic`

Edit 2: I am now using `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` but it still doesn't work.

I use this code to detect if the button is being pressed.

```
- (void)squareOnePressed:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
    {
        NSLog(@"YO");
    }
}
```

But when the button is pressed nothing still happens... So how do I program that ^^^^

Comment: where do you define and how do you define the UIButton? Your question is too broad.

Comment: So did you add the option of UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in 
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:?

Comment: Is the `UIButton` connected to Interface Builder?  If so, you need to make it `weak`.

Comment: @ray It is connected but it has to stay strong because I use constraints written programatically. `self.squareOne = [[UIButton alloc] init];` creates an error when the button is weak

Comment: You shouldn't be calling alloc init on self.squareOne if you created that button in IB -- it's already instantiated, why are you creating a new one?

Comment: @rdelmar I do this because I do this: `[self.view addSubview:self.squareOne];` And if I don't, the constraints get screwed up

Comment: But why are you adding it as a subview of self.view? Didn't you already make it a subview of self.view in IB?

Comment: @rdelmar The answer why is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499193/positioning-uibuttons-at-top-of-screen

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` with `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` in the options parameter.

Add an IBAction to your view controller and connect your button to that. Put your NSLog in the IBAction method. (Do you know how to do this?)

Comment: Now I think I have this figured out now, but what do I put for completion?

Comment: `NULL` is fine if you don't have anything specific you want to do with the animation is done.

Comment: But, I just realized: I am using this code to make sure that the button is press able during animation, but if I use `- (IBAction)` the button pressing won't be detected anyway.

Comment: If you use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` the IBAction will get called during the animation if the button is pressed.

Comment: By `NSLog` do you mean the entire method? Or just a portion. If it's a portion which lines of code does this include?

Comment: I can't do this because I want the method to return a `BOOL`

Comment: Return a `BOOL` to the button? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No I want to return a `BOOL` so in another method I can detect if the button was pressed

Answer (score 0):

Why is your method named `squareOneTouched:`?  Is your `IBAction` triggering that?

If you're subclassing a `UIViewController`, you should just override the `touchesBegan:` method.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
    {
        // This button was hit whilst moving - do something with it here
        NSLog(@"YO");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just named it `squareOneTouched` because I need 5 of these pieces of code, and I worried it would get confusing. Also, when I use this, it still doesn't work

Comment: Then you should add an `if` statement for each square you have inside  the method above.

Did you import `QuartzCore` as the other thread suggested?

Comment: Yes, in both files. I can't do multiple if statements though. This is because I actually want the method to be of type `BOOL` and `return YES;` if the condition is true. I am just using `void` and `NSLog` to see if I can detect the button press

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The constraints are preventing me from interacting with the button. When I remove the programmatically written constraints from the button, it works fine.

Comment: If you had constraints on your buttons, then you shouldn't have been  setting new frames in the animation. You should be adjusting the constraints instead. You should not set any frames on views that use layout constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar No, what I mean is all of the constraints were declared programmatically. No constraint were made using the interface builder

Comment: I didn't say anything in my comment about interface builder. It doesn't matter whether you make the constraints in IB or in code, the same rule applies -- if you're using constraints, don't set frames.

Comment: @rdelmar Then can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499193/positioning-uibuttons-at-top-of-screen without setting frames. Because when I get rid of that section of code the constraints get screwed up

Comment: You already accepted Zhang's answer to that question, and that answer does it without setting any frames. I answered a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268387/auto-layout-equal-space-between-uibuttons/26268470#26268470 that uses spacer views, so it keeps the buttons spaced equally no matter the screen size.

Comment: @rdelmar But he calls alloc and init on btn1

Comment: So? Why is that an issue? He's creating all his buttons in code, so he has to do that.